# Unable to push Repo from "react-native-firebase-starter" template

Tags: firebase, react-native, github

I cloned this repo to start my own project

`https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase-starter`

I have made some modifications and got it setup for Firebase, however I cannot push or rename the Repository.

I ran `npm run rename` and renamed the directory. GitHub still seems to think I am trying to push the orginal repository as my own. 
When I try to push I get:

`Authentication failed. You may not have permission to access the repository or the repository may have been archived...`

How can I keep this template/starter and push a copy of it as my own repository?

I have tried removing all of the inessential files from the Repo and pushing that way. I get the following error:

I expected to be able to use the starter as a starter to get a project up and running... Maybe I am missing something super obvious.

Comment: did my answer make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a `.git` folder within the root of the [react-native-firebase-starter](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase-starter) template, perhaps this is causing issues with pushing this template  since *`git` needs to know where to point to upstream.*

Maybe you could try *initializing the template to your personal git repository* and seeing if this resolves your authentication issue:

1. Create a new repository on [GitHub](https://github.com/). To avoid errors, do not initialize the new repository with `README`, `license`, or `gitignore` files.
2. Initialize the local directory containing the template as a Git repository:

   `git init`
3. Add the files in your new local repository. This stages them for the first commit:

   `git add .`
4. Commit the files that you've staged in your local repository:

   `git commit -m "Initial commit"`
5. At the top of your `GitHub` repository ,created in step 1, copy the remote repository URL.
6. Add the URL for the remote repository where your local repository will be pushed:

   `git remote add origin <remote_repository_url>`
7. Push the changes in your local repository to your upstream repository contained in `GitHub`:

   `git push -u origin master`

You should now be able to push this starter template into your own `GitHub` repository and use it as your own project.

As for the `npm run rename` command: this is a custom `npm` `run` script created by the author of this starter template and it simply runs the `rename.js` [file](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase-starter/blob/master/bin/rename.js) contained within the `.bin` directory of the template's root directory. All this command does is recursively rename the files contained within this template project to the new name specified by your input, so I don't think this is causing the issue. I suspect once your project has been *initialized properly with `git` the authentication issue will disappear* as it will now point upstream to your personal repository.

Hopefully that helps!